# How to effectively know the amount of free space remaining in an relational (SQL) server?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm developing a solution aimed to erase parts of a SQL Server database if it detects it is getting full. For that, I need to know not only the total size of the database, but specially the amount of free size in MB. For the time being I'm using mostly Oracle Database, but the solution should be global if possible.

Doing some research, I found some posts here on SO as well as in other parts of the web with some solutions, but they were often too big (picking up tons of data I'm not interested) or they simply didn't work. Two of the few I managed to get an answer were `SELECT sum(bytes)/1024/1024 \"DB Size in MB\" FROM dba_free_space GROUP BY TABLESPACE_NAME` and the similar `SELECT sum(bytes)/1024/1024 \"DB Size in MB\" FROM dba_free_space`. The problem was it wasn't clear if these were Oracle DB specific and they were giving me clearly wrong results (for instance, the db was almost empty and it was showing half full, or the DB got some new data and the free size got bigger).

So, the point is: how can I know programatically how much of free space, in MB, a SQL Server database currently has? A solution using a SQL query is especially welcomed.

Comment: You can search for the `information_schema` definition. It is implemented in many DBMS. Maybe it covers what you need, though I doubt that. I believe this has to be done for each DBMS in a different way. Second thing is, what you mean by free space? Possibly the figures you get from the catalog only give you the free space in the current files as they are currently allocated. But these files can grow and thus the free space can too. Also, if the free space in a file gets less, that doesn't necessarily mean the file cannot grow, once it's temporarily full and thus gets space again.

Comment: This seems to be a question you would need to ask of the Windows server you put this on and it would to how much space the Database would have and how much is allocated to it.  I'm not sure SQL itself defines limits of space a database can occupy.

Comment: You're not going to find a truly global solution here, each vendor and platform is going to have specific commands for finding both internal and external free space. MS SQL Server, for example, can easily query free space *within* allocated data and log files, but has no (purely) T-SQL command to find unallocated free space on disk.

Comment: Also, seems like a strange requirement to "erase parts of the database" if its getting full; is this, like, a rolling log or something? Why would you need to do that, instead of simply allocating the space you need?

Comment: @BradC because some installations, specially free ones, may have size limitation. E.g. MS SQL free has limit of 9Gb of space per database. So when that size is fully used, old data needs to be erase.